# Как распарсить Generic?

Tags: android, kotlin

Обычно, когда нужно распарсить json я указываю тип класса в который нужно его забиндить. 
Вот так

```
json = "здесь ответ от сервера"
val myClass = Gson().fromJson(json, MyClass::class.java)
```

Но как указать тип класса, если это дженерик?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то примерно так

```
fun parseJson() {
    val json = "здесь ответ от сервера"
    val type = object : TypeToken<B<A>>() {}.type
    val b = Gson().fromJson<B<A>>(json, type)
    val n = b.a?.n
}

class A {
    val n: Int? = null
}

class B<T : Any> {
    val a: T? = null
}
```

Comment: Уау, как это круто спасибо большое!

Comment: @Fanatic рад был помочь)